# How do you alter an HTTP header?

Tags: http-headers

How do you alter an HTTP header? - if I were looking over your shoulder watching you do this, what would I see? Where would you be doing this?-is it different for Apache vs. IIS?

Example: Google makes note that one can/should use a Vary HTTP in certain circumstances:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects
How / where are HTTP headers altered? What would I see you do, while looking over your shoulder, if you were altering an HTTP header?

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 0):

All REST client technologies have a way of setting HTTP headers. Let's look at how you might do it in JavaScript with [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my/url',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'value', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
});
```

If you are on the server side, like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) in Java, there are similar mechanisms.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Vidya - and WHERE is that JavaScript, exactly?--is it in a .htaccess file, or....?? Can you help me visualize exactly where a developer would alter an HTTP header? Thanks, David

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. You can use Apache's `mod_headers` to change headers as shown here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html. But that's for modifying a request from somewhere else before passing it on elsewhere. Or if it is a direct request from JavaScript, that code probably resides on a web page. There are a ton of ways to do this. The scenario matters.

Comment: If this answer helps you, can a brother get an upvote or an accept?